# Laravel Eloquent get a relation that matches a value in pivot table

Tags: php, laravel-5, orm, eloquent, pivot-table

I need to get model that must match with the value stored in a pivot table, but unfortunately i couldn't get the solution.

Here is my schema

```
PEROPERTY TABLE
id


FILTER TABLE
id

FILTER_OPTION TABLE
id
filterId

FILTER_OPTION_TRANSLATE TABLE
optionId
languageId
title

PROPERTY_FILTER TABLE
propertyId
filterId
optionId
```

What i wanto to do is:

```
@foreach($property->filters as $filter)
  {{ $filter->option->translate->title }}
@endforeach
```

but here the problem for me is how to say get option matches optionId in PROPERTY_FILTER TABLE

My models:

```
PROPERTY MODEL
public function filters()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Filter::class, 'PROPERTY_FILTER','propertyId','filterId');
}

FILTER MODEL
public function option()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Filter_Option::class, 'filterId');
}

FILTER OPTION MODEL
public function translate()
{
    return $this
    ->hasOne(Filter_Option_Translate::class, 'optionId')
    ->where('langId', currentLanguage()->langId);
}
```

I hope i can get some help, thanks from now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using pivot table as seperated model.

I was trying to get 3 level far relation through pivot table but even intermediate model couldn't solve my problem, and i just tried a seperated model.

Firstly, i created Property_Filter model that represents property_filter pivot table and I added filter and option methods as below shown:

```
public function filter()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Filter::class, 'filterId');
}

public function option()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Filter_Option::class, 'filterValue');
}
```

Then converted filters relationship method

```
public function filters()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Filter::class, 'PROPERTY_FILTER','propertyId','filterId');
}
```

to

```
public function filters()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Property_Filter::class,'propertyId');
}
```

Now i reach the filter and option selected for iterated filter like below shown:

```
@foreach($properties as $property)
  @foreach($property->filters as $filter) // here i get filters chosen for iterated property
    <span class="caption">{{ $filter->filter->translate->entryTitle }}</span> // here i get iterated filters title (translated)
    <span class="value">{{ $filter->option->translate->entryTitle }}</span> // here i get chosen option for iterated filter not all options belognsto iterated filter
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```